# Python Scraping Issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some data from the NFL Teams Site, and I keep getting an empty string [] in python output.

I'm trying to get the team name and also the link that is with it.

Here is the HTML I'm trying to `findAll()` on:

```
<td customsortid="fullName" id="standingsTile" data="[object Object]" class="rmq-30d300f6" data-radium="true" style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(238, 238, 238); box-sizing: border-box; height: auto; line-height: 40px; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; text-align: right; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: top; box-shadow: rgb(238, 238, 238) 4px 0px 1px; left: 0px; position: absolute; width: 160px;">
    <a href="http://www.nfl.com/teams/profile?team=NE" tabindex="0" data-metrics-link-module="divisionStandings0" data-radium="true" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;">
    <div class="rsv-ae9db127" data-radium="true">
        <div class="rsv-ae9db127" data-radium="true" style="align-items: center; padding: 0px; background-color: transparent; height: 40px; -webkit-box-align: center;">
            <div data-radium="true">
                <img alt="" data-test-id="facemask-image-container" sizes="100vw" src="https://static.nfl.com/static/content/public/static/wildcat/assets/img/logos/teams/NE.svg" width="48" data-radium="true" style="border: 0px; display: block; max-width: 100%; margin-right: 8px; width: 24px;">
            </div>
            <div class="rsv-ae9db127" data-radium="true">
                <div class="rmq-9da922a7" data-radium="true" style="line-height: 1; font-size: 12px; margin-bottom: 0px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); text-transform: none; font-family: &quot;Endzone Sans Medium&quot;, sans-serif; display: none; margin-right: 4px; text-decoration: none;">
                    New England 
                </div>
                <div data-radium="true" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: &quot;Endzone Sans Medium&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1; margin-top: 0px; text-decoration: none; text-transform: none;">
                    Patriots
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rsv-ae9db127" data-radium="true" style="font-size: 10px; line-height: 1; padding-left: 4px; padding-top: 8px;">
            z
        </div>
    </div>
    </a>
</td>
```

Here is my code that keeps giving me a blank list[]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

nfl_url = ("https://www.nfl.com/standings")
webpage = uReq(nfl_url)
page_html = webpage.read()
page_parser = bsoup(page_html , "html.parser")
odd = page_parser.findAll("td", {"class": "rmq-30d300f6"})
print(odd)
```

Where I'm trying to get the team name and link from
https://www.nfl.com/standings

Any Ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There is no element in that class on the sample HTML you posted

Comment: `class="rmq-30d300f6"` Is?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRamirez - That class ID is on the first line of the example.  5th word-block -> `<td customsortid="fullName" id="standingsTile" data="[object Object]" class="rmq-30d300f6"`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine with the example HTML.  However when the URL is re-fetched, it does not have the same data.  Perhaps the page is rendered by javascript, and the server is not serving the actual HTML you have put in the example.  After fetching the page, save a copy for yourself to compare:

```
...
page_html = webpage.read()

print("Read %d bytes" % (len(page_html)))
open("some.html","wt").write(page_html.decode('utf-8'))
...
```

The content saved to "some.html" is markedly different to what you're expecting.

Maybe you can parse the information you desire from the JavaScript input-data returned by the server:

```
...
{"conference":"AMERICAN_FOOTBALL_CONFERENCE","division":"AFC_EAST","teamId":"10043200-2018-239d-5857-a43b18004fb2","fullName":"New England Patriots","nickName":"Patriots","overallWin":11,"overallLoss":5  //etc.
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML content you are after is being generated by Javascript, and so it's not in the original HTML that you scrape from the site.

You should consider using Selenium to load your page, and wait until the element you need is loaded. Something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup


nfl_url = "https://www.nfl.com/standings"
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/your_username/Downloads/chromedriver')
browser.get(nfl_url)
delay = 10
try:
    # Using 'fullName' ID as a check that the relevant portion of the page is loaded.
    # There may be other elements that are more appropriate - up to you to figure out.
    myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'fullName')))
except TimeoutException:
    print( "Loading took too much time!")

page_html = browser.page_source
browser.close()

page_parser = bsoup(page_html , "html.parser")
odd = page_parser.findAll("td", {"class": "rmq-30d300f6"})
print(odd)
```

Note that you will need to specify the path to `chromedriver`, and [download it](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) if it's not on your system already.